# content-type missing in HTTP POST. QT using Webview

Tags: c++, qt, post, qt-creator

Hello this is my first post, sorry i am kinda newbie.

I am trying to make an application where i have Trayicon and on click it will open an borderless `Qwidget` where a webpage is open (an ip adress). I have already had this programmed, but then i had to redo is since i switched to 64x machine and it was targeted for 32x machine. Also i updated QT from 4.8 to 5.5 and q creator form 2.5 to 3.5.
In the old version on my old PC it worked fine and i also have a exe file of my app i just wanted to make some tweeks to it.
Now i am getting this error whenever i tried to connect to the webpage via `QWebview`.

Errors:

---

> content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.
>
> content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.
>
> jit\JITStubs.cpp(2597) : JSC::cti_op_get_by_val

---

Here is the code:

```
QWidget *wind = new QWidget;
    view = new QWebView(wind);
    view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    view->load(urlMaxi);
    if(goFullscreen)
    {
        QDesktopWidget desktop;
        QRect mainScreenSize = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen());
        wind->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/myico.png"));
        view->setFixedHeight(mainScreenSize.height());
        view->setFixedWidth(mainScreenSize.width());
        wind->showFullScreen();
        view->showFullScreen();
    }
    else
    {
       wind->setWindowTitle("Room control");
       wind->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/myico.png"));
       wind->setFixedHeight(heightMaxi);
       wind->setFixedWidth(widthMaxi);
       view->setFixedHeight(heightMaxi);
       view->setFixedWidth(widthMaxi);
       wind->show();
       view->showMaximized();
    }
    connect(view,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(CheckPage()));
```

And here is the second part where i want to connect to webpage its very similar.

```
switch(reason)
 case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
  {
    QWidget *wind = new QWidget;
    view = new QWebView(wind);
    view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    wind->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
    view->load(urlMini);
    wind->setFixedHeight(heightMini);
    wind->setFixedWidth(widthMini);
    view->setFixedHeight(heightMini);
    view->setFixedWidth(widthMini);
    wind->move(QCursor::pos().x()-widthMini,QCursor::pos().y()-heightMini-30);
    QIcon icon(":/icons/myico.png");
    wind->setWindowIcon(icon);
    wind->show();
    view->show();
    view->setFocus();
    view->activateWindow();
    open1=true;
    connect(view,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(CheckPage()));
  }
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i resolved it finaly!

Used `QWebEngineView` instead of `QWebView` thats all, works like a charm.